# Using Python with Regex to search for lines with specific words, and then append those lines to CSV column headings

Tags: python, regex, export-to-csv

I have a long text file called 'maps.txt'.  It contains large amounts of data divided into sections.  Each section with with its own title:

```
measured burnup - core  140828~a
*a bunch of data*

channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes   core 000124~a  k-eff: 1.028343 scale = 1e+14
*a bunch of data*

channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes   core 000124~a  k-eff: 1.028343 scale = 1e+14
*a bunch of data*

scan 170210 fission power at tpd 223207.8   total power  112.210
*a bunch of data*
```

I want to create a Python script that goes through the file, searches for a word in the title using Regex, and then copies that title to a CSV file to be used as column headings:

```
import re
import csv

outputFilename = Sitename + '_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d__%H_%M_%S')
with open(outputFilename + '_output.csv', 'w') as outputCSV:
    search_titles = re.compile('channel|scan|measured')
    for i, line in enumerate(open('maps.txt', 'r')):
        for match in re.finditer(search_titles, line):
                writer = csv.writer(outputCSV).writerow(line)
```

This seems to search up the titles from each section of data fine, but it doesn't output to the CSV file properly.  Instead each letter from each title gets its own cell (I'm opening the CSV file in Excel), and it's not printing them along the top row of the CSV file (I'm hoping to make them column headers).  Instead it returns and prints on the next line.

And ultimately I'd like to truncate the titles and just have a row of column headers like:

```
| measured burnup | channel averaged cell avg fast fluxes |  channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes  |  scan 170210 fission power at tpd  |
```

But since each title is a different length I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: `writerow(line)` will turn each character in the line into a field in the CSV. The argument to `writerow()` should be a list of all the fields you want in the CSV, not a string.

Comment: Why do you loop over all the matches? You should just use an `if` statement to test if the line matches the regexp.

Comment: Why do you use `enumerate`? You never use `i`.

Comment: You should only make `writer` once, when you first open the file, not for each row.

Comment: Look in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and follow the examples on how to use `csvwriter.writerow`.

Comment: If you're just trying to create a single header line from all the matches, you shouldn't call `writerow()` during the loop. Append the truncated part of the line to a list, and at the end of the loop write this list as a single row to the CSV.

Comment: It's not clear how you're truncating the lines to get your header fields. The first one trucates at the `-` character. The next two trucate before `core`.  The last one truncates after `tpd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting rows of single characters is due to this line:

```
writer = csv.writer(outputCSV).writerow(line)
```

[`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects "an iterable of strings" but you are passing it a single string, so it does an implicit conversion of that to a list, which results in the string being split into individual characters.

Instead, you need to accumulate all the headers into a list and write that to the file once you have finished reading the input:

```
with open(outputFilename + '_output.csv', 'w') as outputCSV:
    writer = csv.writer(outputCSV)
    search_titles = re.compile('channel|scan|measured')
    column_headings = []
    for line in open('maps.txt', 'r'):
        if search_titles.match(line):
            column_headings.append(line.strip())
    writer.writerow(column_headings)
```

Note that since you don't use the line number, you don't need `enumerate`.

In terms of removing unnecessary parts of the column names, you need to figure out what is relevant and only match that part. For example, given your sample data you could use a regex like:

```
^\s*(?:channel.*?(?=\s+core)|scan.*tpd|measured.*?(?=\s+-\s+core))
```

Then you modify your code to `search` instead of `match` (to possibly support a match not at the start of the line, although you may not need that):

```
with open(outputFilename + '_output.csv', 'w') as outputCSV:
    writer = csv.writer(outputCSV)
    search_titles = re.compile('^\s*(?:channel.*?(?=\s+core)|scan.*tpd|measured.*?(?=\s+-\s+core))')
    column_headings = []
    for line in open('maps.txt', 'r'):
        m = search_titles.search(line)
        if m is not None:
            column_headings.append(m.group())
    writer.writerow(column_headings)
```

For your sample data, this gives a line:

```
measured burnup,channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes,channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes,scan 170210 fission power at tpd
```

Comment: Looks good, you became quite the Python craftsman. Sometimes I am trying to pick up some Panda's and you post some interesting answers.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you. I've been using python a lot on some home projects and using pandas a fair bit. I still have a lot to learn from some of the experts though. The same applies to this tag and people such as you.

Comment: (this referring to regex)

Comment: @Nick thanks for the reply.  I tried your code but it returns an empty list.  I think it might have something to do with the titles in my maps.txt.  Some of the titles are indented one space, others are indented 3 or 4 spaces.                                Shouldn't search_titles.search(line) look for a match anywhere in the string?

Comment: @Nick Putting `\s*` in front of your regex expression, so `'^\s*(?:channel.*?(?=\s+core)|scan.*tpd|measured.*?(?=\s+-\s+core))'` will let the script see the blank space in front of the titles.

Comment: @JoeBlough I've edited answer to suit. When I tested the code my test data all started at the beginning of the line... You could also remove the `^` from the regex as that will prevent it being anchored to the start of line, although it would also - for example - make `channel` match in `first channel`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: @JoeBlough with the change does the code work as desired?

Comment: @Nick Thanks.  I modified your regex code a little, `^\s*(?:)channel ave.*?(?=\s+core).*?.{17}|scan.*?tpd.{9}|measured.*?\s+-.*?(?=\s+core).*?.{15}` as I decided to add a bit more to the column headings than I originally planned, ` channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes   core 000124~a` and `scan 170210 fission power at tpd 223207.8`.)  I'm not sure if my regex is correct, I used on online regex editor/tester to do it, but it does give me the column headings I want.

Comment: @JoeBlough fair enough, I just based my regex on the data you gave in the question. Anyway, good to know you've got it working.